# How to test (using RTL and Jest) value before and after date expires?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a `<Price />` component, that could receive discounts and if discount date is valid, so the price is shown with discount. But how properly to test this behaviour? I have React Testing Library and Jest.

```
describe('Price', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
   jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  it('Should not apply discount after discount date is expired', () => {
    const expirationDate = new Date();
    expirationDate.setSeconds(expirationDate.getSeconds() + 10);
    const discounts = [
      {
        datetime: expirationDate.toISOString(),
        value: 10,
      },
    ];

    const { getByRole } = render(<Price value={100} discounts={discounts} />);
    const priceRow = getByRole('item', { name: /price/ });
    expect(priceRow).toHaveTextContent('$ 90,00');
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000);
    expect(priceRow).not.toHaveTextContent('$ 90,00');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could solve this issue using `jest.useFakeTimers('modern')` from [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9971).

My solution:

```
describe('Price', () => {
  it('Should not apply discount after discount date is expired', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern');
    const expirationDate = new Date();
    expirationDate.setSeconds(expirationDate.getSeconds() + 10);
    const discounts = [
      {
        datetime: expirationDate.toISOString(),
        value: 10,
      },
    ];
    const { getByRole } = render(<Price value={100} discounts={discounts} />);
    const priceRow = getByRole('item', { name: /price/ });
    expect(priceRow).toHaveTextContent('$ 90,00');
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000);
    expect(priceRow).not.toHaveTextContent('$ 90,00');
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
});
```